# AutoIt _ImageSearch

Tags: google-chrome, bots, autoit

I'm working on a program for a web-based game. I have few errors, I'm not familiar with AutoIt, this is like my fifth time. I found a code online which almost works with a couple of errors I've spent the whole day trying to fix this but nothing yet.

Hope you guys can help me.

[Link to the post where the source is.](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/147258-imagesearch-help-bot/)

I have the images for the search too if you need them.
Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I can write that bot for you. Thats $100.

Comment: @Milos I rather not, I'm not trying to get someone to write the bot for me, I want someone to teach me understand the script.

Comment: wich script? pls copy your "try" in here, so we can help :)     Anyways: ImageSearch is a easy thing, if you just need help with the function say it.

Comment: @Teifun2 My script was without any of the functions and the only problem was the _ImageSearch. This is the script i want to fix.

Comment: @Teifun2 http://pastebin.com/e4i5HdM9, I rather do this over skype messages or something.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTdAx4XPqFg - this is a bot for the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this scipt in the pastebin is just carp XD
i dont get the point of it.

Do you really nead this Script or do you need a example for ImageSearch?

Example for ImageSearch with AutoIt

```
#include <ImageSearch.au3>

Global $x, $y

$prison = _ImageSearch("yourPicture.PNG",1,$x,$y,50)
If $prison = 1 then
  MouseClick("left", $x, $y)
Else
   MsgBox(048,"Attention","I didnt found the picture.")
EndIf
```

The Explanation for the Image Search is here:

```
;===============================================================================
;
; Description:      Find the position of an image on the desktop
; Syntax:           _ImageSearch
; Parameter(s):     
;                   $findImage - the image to locate on the desktop
;                   $tolerance - 0 for no tolerance (0-255). Needed when colors of 
;                                image differ from desktop. e.g GIF
;                   $resultPosition - Set where the returned x,y location of the image is.
;                                     1 for centre of image, 0 for top left of image
;                   $x $y - Return the x and y location of the image
;
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns 1
;                   On Failure - Returns 0 
;
; Note: Use _ImageSearch to search the entire desktop, _ImageSearchArea to specify
;       a desktop region to search
;
;===============================================================================
_ImageSearch($findImage,$resultPosition,ByRef $x, ByRef $y,$tolerance)
```